# Scifi short story where all over the world, babies refuse to be born and so remain inside their mother's wombs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Some decades ago, I read a short story which has the following plot:

All over the world, babies refuse to be born. They remain inside their mother's wombs, but are not born. According to them, there is no reason to be born, as the birth of a baby is the death of a fetus. If a remember well, we know the point of view of babies because one of the women is able to sense the thoughts of her unborn child.

The theme is certainly very common! So, a few additional details: I read it around the year 2000, but the book was a bit older. It was an anthology of scifi tales (can't recall whether from the same author or not). The book was not in English but all the authors were from English speaking countries.

Comment: Quite a common theme. I've found at least 3 in a few seconds of searching; Ariel Dorfman's The Last Song of Manuel Sendero has babies refusing to be born due to the state of political repression that they will face once outside of the womb.*, https://thewalrus.ca/partnerships/amazonfirstnovelaward2016/, https://www.irishtimes.com/culture/books/the-wise-man-a-short-story-by-donal-ryan-1.2471196, etc etc

Comment: The film [Between Heaven and Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Heaven_and_Earth_(1992_film)) has a very similar plot.